# Introduction to functional programming: types exercise

Tags: functional-programming

In the book "Introduction to functional programming" (Bird/Wadlers), I came across the following exercise:

Deduce the type of `fix f x = f (fix f) x`

Following the book's instructions to deduce the type, I made the following deductions:

Starting on the rhs:

```
f :: t1
x :: t2
f (fix f) x :: t3
```

Therefore, `fix :: t1 -> t2 -> t3`

Keep on deducing types on the lfs:

```
f :: t4 -> t2 -> t3

fix f :: t4

f :: t6
fix :: t6 -> t4

(1) t6 = t2 and t4 = t3
t1 = (t2 -> t3) -> t2 -> t3
```

Therefore,

```
fix :: ((t2 -> t3) -> t2 -> t3) -> t2 -> t3
```

Substituting by letters,

```
fix :: ((a -> b) -> a -> b) -> a -> b
```

Which is exactly what I get from the interpreter when I ask for the type of fix.

However, I would like to know if my reasoning is correct and if my assumptions in (1) are correct and would be what the interpreter would infer.

Comment: Just curious which language and interpreter you're using for this

Comment: In order to get the type of `fix`, I used Haskell and Hugs 98. Actually, the book doesn't use any language in particular, just gives knowledge about functional programming.

Comment: It's a really cool question. I just wanted to be able to follow along. Thanks ^_^

Comment: `t4 = t6 -> t4` is impossible. Is it a typo?

Comment: Yes, I agree, that was a mistake. Thanks!